# Oracle deadlock trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a procedure P1.
TABLES T1,T2 and TRIGGER TRG1
Below is the Trigger Event:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE OF RECORD_STATUS
ON T1 WHEN (NEW.RECORD_STATUS='U')
BEGIN
.
--Calling Procedure
P1();
.
END;
```

I am calling a procedure with parameters. Inside procedure `P1` using those parameters I am selecting the data from T1 and doing some validations and inserting into `T2`.

After Successful insert I am updating the `RECORD_STATUS='I'` in the the procedure.

Now I performed below statement:

```
UPDATE T1 SET RECORD_STATUS='U'
```

Since the trigger event occurs here it is calling my procedure and inside the procedure since I am updating the same column again trigger is firing and leads to  dead lock. Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, avoid using business logics inside a trigger, it looks like an application design flaw. Any references to the columns of the trigger owner should use `:NEW` and `:OLD` prefixes within the trigger rather than using a select or update queries directly on them in the trigger or anywhere else as you are doing.

Comment: :new and :old values are not available in statement trigger, they exist only on row level trigger, I. E. With FOR EACH ROW clause

Comment: Does the table has any bitmap index or do you run an autonomous transaction  inside the procedure?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Right. I noticed now that `for each row` is missing, which means the `when` clause should not have let the trigger to compile.

Comment: It sounds like your logic is a bit complicated, it's certainly hard for us to follow what you're trying to do. I suggest you post the simplest possible version of your code.

Answer (score -1):

First of all some advice, NEVER use triggers unless your desperate.

If your already updating the table in a stored procedure, add the logic into your P1 procedure, or create a second procedure with the additional functionality and call it from P1.

Good citizenship is part of database development.  All transactions on those tables should follow the same order.  Using a trigger to update the same table is not good citizenship.

If you really have to do something like this, one thing you can try, is to use an [Autonomous Transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm)

Comment: Downvoting.  Autonomous transactions are arguably just as misused and abused as triggers are.  That's not to say one cannot contrive a legitimate design using them both together, but I read this post as an unqualified endorsement of autonomous transactions as a way to fix questionable trigger-based designs.

Comment: Triggers have their uses. Autonomous transactions have their uses. Both are probably over-used, but neither is a replacement for the other.

Comment: I have used atonomous transaction inside the procedure which is handling the update. However, After a careful review of all the possibilities I dropped trigger as it is causing recursive Trigger. I created a wrapper program to call the procedure.